# Multiple Arduinos, same name - Windows 10 Game Controllers

Tags: arduino-leonardo, arduino-pro-micro

I am making some SimPit panels and SimRacing devices, and I've run into an annoying issue. I have  multiple Arduinos (Leonardos and ProMicros) that show up as the same "Controller Names" (See Image)

EDIT: **In the Game Controllers (joy.cpl) windows of Windows 10**, where does the name "Arduino Leonardo" come from?, so that I can rename each, so they show up listed as something different like: Leonardo 1, Leonardo 2, Leonardo 3?

I imagine this is a change to the boot-loader and nothing to do with anything via Arduino IDE?

Thank you for your time, and let me know if more info/explanation is needed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, edited, where does the name "Arduino Leonardo" come from?

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/boards.txt#L387

Comment: That didn't work, it changed the name in "Bus Reported device description" in device manager (https://i.imgur.com/TgIgXBR.png), but not in the joy.cpl "Game Controllers" window

also I purged all USB Serial devices to be sure there was no lingering windows drivers overwriting the changes

Comment: Then it may be in the .inf file for the driver in Windows.

Comment: So, if that's true, then it'll likely change all the devices using that driver together to the same name?

Not 3 devices using the same inf to 3 unique names?

I'll test ASAP

Comment: If it is the case then you'll need to make three distinct devices with unique VID/PID combinations and have three separate drivers for them.

Comment: it appears that windows is able to distinguish more than VID/PID of a USB device ... there is mention of VID/PID/REV in the *inf* files ... REV is the device revision number which is the bcdDevice field in the USB device descriptor ... the bcdDevice field would have to be different in each Leonardo ... the *inf* file would have to be edited to create a different device name for each REV version

Comment: start on the windows side of the problem ... write arduino code that sets the `bcdDevice` field to some number, such as 4 .... edit the `inf` file to match `VID/PID/REV` ... choose REV = 4 ... windows should hopefully detect Leonardo ... next, change REV to 5 ... if windows detects an unknown device, then you have a way to distinguish Leonardos

Comment: Thank you both I'm going to try this new path ASAP, I will update when I can

Comment: @jsotola why are these comments, instead of an actual answer? This is detailed enough to absolutely justify being its own step by step answer, which can then also be found by searching (both on-site and through google).

Answer (score 2):

Windows is likely assigning the inbox driver to use based on the VID/PID of the USB device.  Take care changing those values, as you may not be able to easily reprogram the devices.

There is a Device Firmware Update (DFU) technique where if a pin is low at startup / USB init, the VID/PID are returned as different values

Comment: Meaning I should setup a "board" with the changed VID/PID in arduino IDE?

DFU if you mean the vulgar acronym, I can do that ... I am that ;)

Comment: Certainly not the vulgar term. I was referring to Device Firmware Update (DFU).  If you setup the board(s) to use a VID/PID that the inbox joy stick driver recognized, then Windows will recognize the devices as such. The key to this is being able to make sure that you can still get the Arduino IDE to recognize the board as well.  I don't have any leonardo boards, but I have done this with one of the other Arduino boards... though it was some time ago.

Comment: Correction:  The project I was thinking of emulated a keyboard not a joy stick

Comment: Haha lol DFU is permanently ruined for acronyms, ill never see beyond the vulgar one now.. Thanks for all the info